# why nullspace is the largest subspace perpendicular to the row space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The proof from my textbook is

**"If x were a vector orthogonal to the row space, but not in the nullspace, then the dimension of $C(A^T)^\perp$ would be at least n — r + 1. But this would be too large for both $C(A^T)$ and $C(A^T)^\perp$ to fit in $R^n$.  So, the nullspace is the largest subspace perpendicular to the row space"**

I don't quite understand why it has something to do with $R^n$?
For example, let's say we have a matrix A
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  -1&  1&  3& 2\\ 
 2&  -1&  1&  5& 1\\ 
 3&  -1&  1&  7& 0\\ 
 0&  1&  -1&  -1& -3
\end{pmatrix}$$

Reduce A to the row-echelon form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  -1&  1&  3& 2\\ 
 0&  1&  -1& -1& -3\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Because there are two pivots, so the dimension of nullspace is 3. And if there exists a vector orthogonal to the row space, but not in the nullspace, why the the dimension of $C(A^T)^\perp$ would be at least 4 (even 4 is OK,because there are 4 columns) and why this would be too large for both $C(A^T)$ and $C(A^T)^\perp$ to fit in $R^5$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that ${\rm rank}(A)=r$, then by the dimension theorem,
the dimension of the nullspace (denote $N(A)$) is $n-r$. 
Also it is easy to show that $N(A)\subseteq C(A^{T})^\perp$, so
we have  $\dim(C(A^T)^\perp)\ge n-r$. Now, the author gives a 
proof by contradiction as what you wrote in **boldface**, that
one suppose that there exists a nonzero vector ${\bf x}\in C(A^T)^\perp$
but ${\bf x}\notin N(A)$. Then by the preceding result,
$\dim(C(A^T)^\perp)\ge n-r\color{red}{+1}$, which finally get the contradiction
that 
$$\dim(R^n)=\dim(C(A^T))+\dim(C(A^T)^\perp)\ge r+(n-r+1)=n+1>\dim(R^n).$$
Notice: $\dim(C(A^T))={\rm rank}(A).$

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the relation to $R^n$ either. A vector is perpendicular to the first row if and only if its image under the matrix has first coordinate $0$ and similarly for the other rows. Hence a vector is perpendicular to all rows (and hence to their span) if and only if it is mapped to zero by the matrix.